# std::chrono::duration passed as a method parameter

Tags: c++, datetime

I have this method:

```
string tpToString(const system_clock::time_point &tp)
{
    string formatStr { "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" };
    return date::format(formatStr, date::floor<microseconds>(tp) );
}
```

This method produces a string such as:

```
2021-02-09 20:53:10.123456
```

That's great. It uses Howard Hinnant's date library. I just found myself hitting an instance where an API is returning an error if I offer a time out to microseconds. It wants milliseconds. So I can do that with a second method:

```
string tpToStringInMillis(const system_clock::time_point &tp)
{
    string formatStr { "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" };
    return date::format(formatStr, date::floor<milliseconds>(tp) );
}
```

That works. But what I'd prefer to do is pass (as an optional parameter) the duration, something like this:

```
string tpToString(const system_clock::time_point &tp, chrono::duration dur = milliseconds)
{
    string formatStr { "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" };
    return date::format(formatStr, date::floor<dur>(tp) );
}
```

However, this produces an error "no matching function for call to 'floor'". I'm actually surprised that it doesn't complain about the function definition, as milliseconds is a typedef.

Suggestions?

I suppose I could pass a lambda, but that's starting to get ugly.

Comment: make the method a template on duration type? or does it need to be changeable at runtime?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Interesting. No, it doesn't need to be changeable, although I don't know how I'd do that, either without making the syntax to use it ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make `tpToString` a template you can allow the caller to choose the accuracy at compile time.

```
template <typename FloorType = microseconds>
string tpToString(const system_clock::time_point& tp)
{
    string formatStr{ "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" };
    return date::format(formatStr, date::floor<FloorType>(tp));
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << tpToString(system_clock::now()) << "\n";
    std::cout << tpToString<milliseconds>(system_clock::now()) << "\n";
    std::cout << tpToString<seconds>(system_clock::now()) << "\n";
    std::cout << tpToString<minutes>(system_clock::now()) << "\n";
}
```